# Note: An exception occurred while getting the Javadoc. See log for details.-eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, javadoc

I added java doc location for the SWT (org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.102.1.v20140206-1358.jar) as "http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/" but after that, when I move the mouse pointer to a SWT class name or method name on the editor, it popups above message. How to solve that and get the actual java doc details.

Comment: If you follow that link, you will notice that it is a redirect to a non-javadoc page.

Comment: Install the 'Eclipse SDK' if you want source and JavaDoc for everything in Eclipse. The update site for this is http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4 for Eclipse Luna

Comment: @greg-449 Will it install the java docs for SWT external jar too?

Comment: No, but SWT is included in Eclipse.

Comment: @greg-449 - but I wan to set the docs for SWT. How to do that?

Comment: Thanks a lot greg. I Installed the 'Eclipse SDK' via download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4 and now it is ok. I see all the java doc support when I take my mouse over.. So does that "Eclipse SDK" download all the documentation for new plugins I added to eclipse?

Answer (score 11):

In Eclipse do the following:

1. Go to *Windows* -> *Preferences*.
2. Click *Installed JREs*.
3. Click *Add*.
4. Select *Standard VM*.
5. Click *Next*.
6. Click *Directory*
7. Choose your Sun JDK folder.
8. Click *Finish*.
9. Tick your Sun JDK folder from the list.
10. Click *OK*.
11. Restart Eclipse.

Problem solved!

Comment: Another step was needed for me. After the above do: Project, Preferences, Java Build Path, then scroll down to JRE System Library and change that to the one you specified above.

Comment: Chris' step didn't work for me. What I did was, under Windows > Preferences > Installed JREs -> Execution Environment -> Pick the Execution Environment your project is using -> Compatible JREs -> set JDK as default (instead of JRE)